# How to build a custom binding by having WSHttpBinding security and GZip compression?

Tags: c#, wcf, gzip, custom-binding

i am facing a problem here.
I am doing a client/server project, which is WCF web service calling to get data.Due to huge data of transfering, i got to change my binding to custom binding programmatically(not by config file.)

I am creating a new user-define binding aka custom binding.
example of the class is :

```
public class MyCustomBinding : CustomBinding
```

and override a function BindingElementCollection:

```
public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
{
   WSHttpBinding wSHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding("RMSKeberosBinding"); //this is to load the configuration from app.config. because i want to copy the setting of wsHttpConfig to my custom binding.

   BindingElementCollection wSHttpBindingElementCollection = wSHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements();

   TransactionFlowBindingElement transactionFlowBindingElement = wSHttpBindingElementCollection.Remove&lt;TransactionFlowBindingElement&gt;();
   SymmetricSecurityBindingElement securityElement = wSHttpBindingElementCollection.Remove&lt;SymmetricSecurityBindingElement&gt;();
   MessageEncodingBindingElement textElement = wSHttpBindingElementCollection.Remove&lt;MessageEncodingBindingElement&gt;();
   HttpTransportBindingElement transportElement = wSHttpBindingElementCollection.Remove&lt;HttpTransportBindingElement&gt;();

   GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement gzipElement = new GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement(); // this is from microsoft sample. i want to add gzip as a compress to my message.

   BindingElementCollection newCol = new BindingElementCollection();
   newCol.Add(transactionFlowBindingElement);
   newCol.Add(securityElement);
   newCol.Add(gzipElement);
   newCo .Add(transElement);
   return newCol;
}
```

what i am trying to do is copy all setting from wshttpbinding, and add on gzip as the message encoder.
**Compress an encrypted data will lead to a bigger size of the original data size.**
this is because the SymmetricSecurityBindingElement from WSHttpBinding did the encryption.
How to do this in correct way? i want the security setting from wshttpbinding, and also the gzip to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use a behavior to apply compression accordingly:

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/03/29/441398.aspx

EDIT: I perhaps should also include the link to the Behavior based compression:

http://weblogs.shockbyte.com.ar/rodolfof/archive/2006/04/06/5632.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I had viewed the link you gave me previously. Sorry, but i can't see where is the place using the same behavior of WSHttpBinding's security? Does the link u gave, include the encryption?

Comment: From my experience using the code that I linked to, even though the entire encrypted message itself is compressed, it did not lead to a larger message size but instead reduced the message size. The message is at its core is just SOAP (i.e. verbose text), so by utilizing compression you should see gains. Am I misunderstanding what you want to do?

Comment: Hi MattK, thanks for the reply.
For my experience in it, whenever i add SymmetricSecurityBindingElement and GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement into the binding element collection(please refer to the code at above),the message is always encrypted at first, then only proceed to compress. I had use Fiddler to check the bandwidth usage. It is so huge after compress an encrypted message. I dunno how to solve this.

By the way, the link you had send me, can u show me where is the part that encrypting the message? i can't manage to find the code to encrypt. 

Thanks MattK.

Comment: My apologies...I had used the behavior based compression so that I could use the standard WSHttpBinding instead of a custom binding. I've edited my initial answer to include the link to that code.